# Grails Paginate: Always Show the Previous Button

Tags: grails, pagination

I want to display list of data in a table with pagination option. So I am using grails pagination tag like this:

```
<g:paginate total="${totalCount}"  params="${params}"/>
```

It show the pagination like below
[image: Grails pagination 1st view]

Here there is no `Previous` button is shown. But when I click on any other number rather than 1 it show `Previous` button like this: [image]

I want to do following:

- Display `Previous` and `Next` button always
- Disable `Previous` or `Next` button for first / last page
- Highlight currently selected number and disable it.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Grails paginate option initially focus on 1st page .So you don't have previous option initially .You can Datatables link is provided in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html instead of pagination plugin.Pull all data initially then show whatever want.

Comment: If data size is huge then?

Comment: @EmdadulSawon use server side data table https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: @MikeW Thanks a lot. :)